# Cypress - How to stub an import/function after an assertion sequentially?

Tags: reactjs, cypress, assertion, stubbing

**Question:** How to stub an import/function after an assertion?

**Scenario:**

- A button with customhook called. Based on the response of customhook (false/true), the button text will be changing.
- During initial render, customHook returns false and the text is xxxx.
- After clicking the button, the customHook returns true and the text will be changed to yyyy

**Solution tried:**

1. mount the button (during which a customhook will be called and return false)
2. assert the button text to be xxxx
3. stubbed the custom hook to return true.
4. cy.get("button").click();
5. assert the new button text to be yyyy

**Outputs:**

1. The above fails in step 2 . Looks like Stubbing (step 3) happened before step 2 assertion.
2. If i dont stub, only step 5 fails.

So ultimately, based on the outputs, it is clear that Stubbing is not happening sequentially with assertion.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Do you have a `setWhatever()` method to set the state?